# How to replace gets() function in C programming?

Tags: c, linux, windows, file, codeblocks

So basically this works perfectly fine on Windows CodeBlocks (I just realised that I'm using gets() and it accesses more storage but I forgot) and it doesn't work on Linux in the terminal. How can I fix this?

```
 char file_name[25];
 printf("File Name = ");
 gets(file_name);
```

I tried fgets(), but it doesn't work.

```
 char file_name[25];
 printf("File Name = ");
 fgets(file_name,25,stdin);
```

In Linux it doesn't print anything and in CodeBlocks it prints File name = and when you enter the file name it says: "Cannot open file: Invalid argument".

Comment: please provide a [mre], it sounds like your problem is not with `fgets`

Comment: See my answer for a `gets` replacement using `fgets` (_with_ prompt): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011769/check-if-all-values-entered-into-char-array-are-numerical/65013419#65013419 It has functions that do exactly what you're looking for. Note that the reason your `fgets` code is failing is that it does _not_ strip the newline [as `gets` does].