# Reading input from user and use it as argument to executable using Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, user-input

Here's my code. The problem involves the target "run_NumberOfSensorReadings". I want to grab an input from the user, and then pass it as an argument to the executable file. If we disable the ".SILENT" target, the value of "NUM" is not passed as an argument, it simply shows "./output". What am I missing here?

```
.SILENT: #dont echo commands as we run them.

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes
LDFLAGS = -lm
SRC = ${wildcard *.c}
OBJS = ${SRC:.c=.o}
EXEC = output

valgrind: ${EXEC}
    valgrind ./${EXEC}

all: ${EXEC}

run_NumberOfSensorReadings: ${EXEC}
    @read -p "Number of Sensor Readings:" NUM;
    ./${EXEC} ${NUM}    

run: ${EXEC}
    ./${EXEC}

${EXEC}: ${OBJS}
    ${CC} -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS}

%.o:%.c
    ${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o ${EXEC}
```

Comment: The Makefile is the wrong tool for this. Put the `read` and the invocation into a [bash] script file. Invoke that from the make. But, why isn't this user prompt in the C program???

Comment: Ok, good observation. So best way to correct this is use a bash script to grab the user input and then run the application, correct? What do you mean by putting the user prompt in the C program? I'm planning to use the argc and argv to do further computations.

Comment: Are you prompting the user for input as just a test in this Makefile? Or, will this be a regular mode of using the program? Just have the C program do (e.g.) `printf("Number of Sensor Readings:"); fflush(stdout); int num; scanf("%d",&num);` For some better code to do this, see my answer: [check if all values entered into char array are numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013419)

Comment: I know about the user input. What I wanted to do is to give the program the parameter represented by "NUM" as an argument, and obtained via argv, probably using a function like `sscanf()`. So the user input inside the C program wouldn't be necessary. Then, I would use bash to do the job more easily, without having to type "./output" and then choose a number to put as an argument of "./output". Thanks a lot, Craig. I'm gonna be looking this code about checking values inside char array, thanks for it as well!

Comment: User input with shell programs is notoriously bad to do portably, even for so modest things as character terminal input. BUT: this is not what your real problem is. The part you are missing is that **every line of a `make` recipe is executed in a separated shell invocation**, which means that you can't use variables like you are used to in normal shell programming. For simple cases, concatenate the `make` recipe lines with \. If you find this behaviour annoying (there are pro's and con's) you can give a pseudotarget `.ONESHELL:` in the makefile which forces recipe execution within one shell