# How do I check if the variable is a string?

Tags: c

I've got a problem because I don't know how to identify whether the user inserted a number or a string or a char. In this code I've only considered the option when the user inserts a number in a specific range (0,9) but I don't know what to do if the user inserts string or char, I want to stop the program if the user inserts a string. But I don't know how to do it.

````
void check()                                           
{                                                    
    int w =0,k=0;
    printf("Liczba ruchow: %d\n", r++); 
    printf("Wybierz wiersz : ");
    scanf("%d/n",&w);
    while(w<0 || w>9)
    {
        printf("Bledna wartosc prosze wpisac raz jeszcze :" );
        scanf("%d/n",&w);
    }
    printf("Wybierz kolumne : ");
    scanf("%d/n",&k);
    while(k<0 || k>9)
    {
        printf("Bledna wartosc prosze wpisac raz jeszcze :" );
        scanf("%d/n",&k);
    } ```
````

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of elements successfully read. So, since you're reading only one, then if it returns a value other than 1, then something went wrong.

Comment: Always check what `scanf` (or any function in the `scanf` family) [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: And almost *never* have a trailing space in our `scanf` format. Though in your case you don't have it, since you have the wrong slash for that.

Comment: And most experienced C programmers recommend that you forget that `scanf` even exist. Read lines (with e.g. `fgets`) and then use other ways to parse and validate the input (`sscanf` or `strtol` for example).

Comment: *I want to stop the program if the user inserts a string. But I don't know how to do it*  Stop using `scanf()` - it's meant to **scan** data that is **f**ormatted in a known way.  Since you don't know what the data is, you have to read it as a string of `char` values and parse it yourself.

Comment: How do I check it ?

Comment: See my answer: [Check if all values entered into char array are numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013419/5382650)

Comment: If range of the number in question is 0-9, try using `getchar()` instead of `scanf()`, use the `isdigit()` function to see if it is a digit, and then subtract the value of the character `'0'` to convert a digit character to a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to directly test for a single numeric character, you might allow for someone accidently entering in more than one digit or entering in non-numeric characters by using the "%s" format in scanf and then evaluating the entered string.   Following is a snippet of code with some revisions to your initial code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void check()
{
    int w = 0, k = 0, r = 1, len = 0;
    char chk[16];   /* Work variable */

    printf("Liczba ruchow: %d\n", r++);
    printf("Wybierz wiersz : ");
    len = scanf("%s",chk);

    while (1)
    {
        if (len == 1 && isdigit(chk[0]))
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("Bledna wartosc prosze wpisac raz jeszcze :" );
        len = scanf("%s",chk);
    }

    w = (char)atoi(chk);

    printf("Wybierz kolumne : ");
    len = scanf("%s",chk);

    while (1)
    {
        if (len == 1 && isdigit(chk[0]))
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("Bledna wartosc prosze wpisac raz jeszcze :" );
        len = scanf("%s",chk);
    }

    k = (char)atoi(chk);

}

int main()
{
    check();
    printf("Do widzenia\n");    /* Hope I got my farwell right */
    return 0;
}
```

The revised code utilizes functions from the "ctype.h" include file to make sure that the entry is numeric, and also checks the length of the entry to ensure that only one digit was entered.  Following is some test output at my terminal.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckNumeric/bin/Release$ ./CheckNumeric 
Liczba ruchow: 1
Wybierz wiersz : w
Bledna wartosc prosze wpisac raz jeszcze :hello
Bledna wartosc prosze wpisac raz jeszcze :8
Wybierz kolumne : hi
Bledna wartosc prosze wpisac raz jeszcze :5
Do widzenia
```

Try that out and see if it meets the spirit of your project.