# Unable to scan the input from user in structure without using both fgets and scanf

Tags: c

I am trying to make a structure to store and print info in file. The problem is when I try to use only scanf or fgets to scan the string with spaces it does not work, but it works when I use both. I want to know:

- why it works only when both are used and not individually?
- is there a way to use only one of them?

````
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    char name[100];
    char id[100];
    float cgpa;
    char branch[100];
};

int
main()
{
    int n;

    printf("enter no of students:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");
    FILE *fptr;

    fptr = fopen("text4.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fptr, "NAME\tID\tCGPA\tBRANCH\n");
    struct student stud[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("enter name :");
        fgets(stud[i].name, 100, stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", stud[i].name);

        printf("enter id:");
        fgets(stud[i].id, 100, stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", stud[i].id);

        printf("enter cgpa:");
        scanf("%f", &stud[i].cgpa);

        printf("enter branch:");
        fgets(stud[i].branch, 100, stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", stud[i].branch);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", &stud[i].name);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\t", &stud[i].id);
        fprintf(fptr, "%f\t", stud[i].cgpa);
        fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", &stud[i].branch);
    }

    fclose(fptr);
}
```the below code is the one which causes an error in which it doesn't scan THE NAME , THE ID OR THE BRANCH AND SKIPS OF TO 'enter cgpa:' when i run the code AND THEN THE CODE TERMINATES as soon as I press enter after entering the cgpa.

    #include<stdio.h>

    struct student{
    char name[100];
    char id[100];
    float cgpa;
    char branch[100];
    };

    int main(){
    int n;
    printf("enter no of students:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("text4.txt","w");
    fprintf(fptr,"NAME\tID\tCGPA\tBRANCH\n");
    struct student stud[100];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("enter name :");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",stud[i].name);

    printf("enter id:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",stud[i].id);

    printf("enter cgpa:");
    scanf("%f",&stud[i].cgpa);

    printf("enter branch:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",stud[i].branch);
    printf("\n");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    fprintf(fptr,"%s\t",&stud[i].name);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s\t",&stud[i].id);
    fprintf(fptr,"%f\t",stud[i].cgpa);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s\n",&stud[i].branch);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    }

THIS IS HOW IT APPEARS IN THE TERMINAL:

enter no of students:1

enter name :enter id:enter cgpa:9.8
enter branch:
PS C:\Users\new user\code\c tutorials> 


the below code is the one in which I use fgets() causes an error such that it doesn't scan THE NAME OR THE BRANCH AND SKIPS OF TO "enter id:"and then to 'enter cgpa:'when I run the codeAND THEN THE CODE TERMINATES as soon as I press enter after entering the cgpa.

    #include<stdio.h>

    struct student{
    char name[100];
    char id[100];
    float cgpa;
    char branch[100];
    };

    int main(){
    int n;
    printf("enter no of students:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("text4.txt","w");
    fprintf(fptr,"NAME\tID\tCGPA\tBRANCH\n");
    struct student stud[100];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("enter name :");
    fgets(stud[i].name,100,stdin);

    printf("enter id:");
    fgets(stud[i].id,100,stdin);

    printf("enter cgpa:");
    scanf("%f",&stud[i].cgpa);

    printf("enter branch:");
    fgets(stud[i].branch,100,stdin);
    printf("\n");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    fprintf(fptr,"%s\t",&stud[i].name);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s\t",&stud[i].id);
    fprintf(fptr,"%f\t",stud[i].cgpa);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s\n",&stud[i].branch);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    }

THIS IS HOW IT APPEARS IN THE TERMINAL:

enter no of students:1

enter name :enter id:ait22
enter cgpa:9.8
enter branch:
PS C:\Users\new user\code\c tutorials>
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should apply some proper indentation to your code. Also you do not show the code that does not work. How do you try to read the input using only `scanf` or `fgets`? What does "does not work" mean? Please provide sample input, outptu and expected output.

Comment: If the code you show, works as expected, you are doing something wrong. `%[^\n]s` is not what you think i is. `%[]` is a format specifier and `s` is not related to is. That means, you must enter an extra `s` after your input. Otherwise scanning will fail at that point. I assume your calls to `fgets` are just cleaning up what you left in the buffer with the previous `scanf` calls.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` This will leave `\n` in the buffer that is read with next `fgets`. You should generally not mix `fgets` and `scanf`.

Comment: My answer [Check if all values entered into char array are numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013419/5382650) may give you some insight.

Comment: Regardless of all the other issues that have been mentioned, why are you doing `fgets(x, ...)` followed by `scanf(..., x)`. (where x = stud[i].branch).  You read data into x with fgets, and then immediately attempt to read different data into x.  Why?

Comment: @Gerhardh I have updated the post with the code that does not work . Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The `fgets` call reads up to *and including* a newline in the input. After your initial `scanf("%d", &n);`, the newline from your input is still pending. The next input operation will read — or attempt to read — that newline.

In your case, with the working code you present, that's your `fgets()`.

Since you then read a few strings with `%[^\n]s`, each time after that a newline lingers which must be read away first with `fgets` before the next `%[^\n]s` will read anything.

(As Jonathan correctly remarked, `%[...]s` is *not* an extension of the '%s' conversion; it is an `%[...]`conversion, after which a literal `s` is expected (which according to Jonathan is never matched, since it has been read as part of the `%[...]`conversion).)

The `%f`, by contrast, skips any whitespace including newline until it hits and reads a number, which is why it works without a preceding `fgets` (but inserting one shouldn't hurt either).

If you want to read single strings with spaces in them you have indeed to  rely on some non-space separator like newline. In the end there is no way around tracking the input format carefully, including what newlines are there and how you skip them.

Comment: You should note that a scan set `%[…]` is not a modifier for the `%s` conversion specifier but a wholly separate conversion specifier.  Further, the `s` after `%[^\n]s` always fails to match, terminating the input processing.  When the `s` is the last character in the format string, as here, the error goes unnoticed — there is no way for `scanf()` to report the trouble. But if it were used in a bigger format string, that matching failure would matter. The scan set reads until the next character is `'\n'` or EOF, and then looks for an `s`, but the next character is not `s` (it is `'\n'` or EOF)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wasn't even aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: See [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) for the POSIX specification, which aligns closely with the Standard C specification.  Ideally, there should be a length too (`%99[^\n]`) to avoid overflows.  The `scanf()` family of functions are diabolically tricky to use.  The standard advice to read lines using `fgets()` and parse using `sscanf()` is also likely sensible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually, `scanf` is really easy to use for basic tasks (scan tokens without whitespace in them). For anything more complicated you want a library tailored to parsing text; many languages come with such libraries built-in or are explicitly designed around pattern extraction. In standard C all this is error-prone and cumbersome. As an aside, I don't think that line-oriented parsing makes things much simpler; you still have to parse them, don't you? The main benefit is per-line error recovery. You buy that with additional constraints on the input format (namely in lines).