# C Visual Studio goto skipping scanf_s

Tags: c, label, scanf, goto

I'm coding in C on visual studio and can't seem to figure out a fix for scanf_s scanning only once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int duration;
    int cost;
    printf("1 day = 50$\nFor students:\n2 days = 90$\n3 days = 120$\n");
    question_1:
    printf("What's your stay duration in days?\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &duration);
    if (duration == 1)
    {
        printf("That will be 50$.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (duration == 2 || duration == 3)
        {
        question_2:
            printf("Are you a student?\n");
            char answer[20];
            scanf_s("%s", &answer, sizeof(answer));
            if (strcmp(answer, "yes") == 0)
            {
                    if (duration == 2)
                    {
                        printf("That will be 90$.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("That will be 120$.");
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                if (strcmp(answer, "no") == 0)
                {
                    cost = duration * 50;
                    printf("That will be %d$.", cost);
                }
                else
                {
                    goto question_2;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            goto question_1;
        }
    }
}
```

When inputting a word instead of a number for "duration" the program repeatedly prints "What's your stay duration in days?" instead of scanning for another input, what should I change?

Comment: Go see whoever taught you about `goto`, and tell them they're fired as your instructor, and find a new one that can teach you the proper way to write this code.

Comment: I've just been checking on the Internet for the most part, what do I change to fix the problem at hand?

Comment: @Genata339 You need to clear the input buffer after an invalid input.

Comment: *"When inputting a word instead of a number"*. That text will stay in the input buffer, until there is a fomat specifer which can read it – it is not discarded. Always check the return value from `scanf` family function, which will tell you what happened. When you might get "erroneous input from user" **don't even use those functions**. Use `fgets` and apply `sscanf` to the string, and validate all user input, in a loop, so you can easily throw away a bad input.

Comment: As you can see I'm pretty new to C

Comment: You're _not_ checking the return value of `scan_s`. If the number scan was sucessful, it will return 1. If not, it returns 0 but the non-number text _stays_ in the stream. So, you'll need to remove it with (e.g.) `while getchar() != '\n');` But, for prompted user input, it's better to use `fgets` and `strtol`. See my answer: [Check if all values entered into char array are numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013419/5382650)

Comment: Welcome! The `scanf` type functions are presented to users, but they are really tricky. Well done for using MS so-called safer versions correctly (buffer size). You'll go far.

Comment: Visual studio pretty much forces me to add _s to scanf unless I don't wanna run the code.

Comment: MS wants to rule the world and *warns* about standard functions it thinks you should not be using. Please stick to C standard functions. Before any `#include` directives I place the following 3 lines in MSVC code: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`. Sadly some of their so-called "safer" versions are no safer at all, or there are safe ways to use the standard function. In particular their `scanf_s` family is even trickier to use than the standard functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the input buffer after an invalid input. For example

```
printf("1 day = 50$\nFor students:\n2 days = 90$\n3 days = 120$\n");

question_1:;
int result;
do
{
    printf("What's your stay duration in days?\n");
    result = scanf_s("%d", &duration);

    if ( result != 1 )
    {
        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
    }
} while ( result != 1 );
```

Pay attention to that instead  of goto statements and labels it is much better to use loops. Try to rewrite your program using loops.

Also pay attention to the semicolon after the label

```
question_1:;
```

The problem is that in C you may not place labels before declarations. So the null statement helps to resolve the problem.

Comment: That is so terrible. Just use `fgets` for random user input. It's so much easier to control.

Comment: @WeatherVane There is nothing terrible to use scand_s.

Comment: Oh there is, because it is even easier to get wrong than the regular `scanf`. Anyway, for your "fix" the input might not have even ended with `'\n'`.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you are afraid to use  valid constructions then stop programming. It is not the first time when you are saying about your obsession.

Comment: I understand how to use `scanf`. But to keep things simple I am by no means the only person to advise avoiding `scanf` for user input, where it is easy to get knotted up.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good luck! Do not use scanf if it is too complicated for you.:)

Comment: Don't be facetious. The `fgets` solution is shorter and easier.

Answer (score 0):

This version of the code works as intended by me, the poster and a C novice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int duration;
    int cost;
    int check;
    printf("1 day = 50$\nFor students:\n2 days = 90$\n3 days = 120$\n");
    question_1:
    do
    {
        printf("What's your stay duration in days?\n");
        check = scanf_s("%d", &duration);

        if (check != 1)
        {
            while (getchar() != '\n');
        }
    } while (check != 1);
    if (duration == 1)
    {
        printf("That will be 50$.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (duration == 2 || duration == 3)
        {
        question_2:
            printf("Are you a student?\n");
            char answer[20];
            scanf_s("%s", &answer, sizeof(answer));
            if (strcmp(answer, "yes") == 0)
            {
                    if (duration == 2)
                    {
                        printf("That will be 90$.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("That will be 120$.");
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                if (strcmp(answer, "no") == 0)
                {
                    cost = duration * 50;
                    printf("That will be %d$.", cost);
                }
                else
                {
                    goto question_2;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            goto question_1;
        }
    }
}
```