# I didn't write printf but in output it duplicates the input

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaEh8.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
char s[50];
int n,i;
int main(){
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s",s);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

it shouldn't give the output but it duplicates the input and gives output
for example try to write:4 hello how are you it won't give, but if you copy paste the input as in the example it will give that:(guys I wrote each of them in separate line but site doesn't show it like this. Also, this bug won't happen if you write it one by one you have to copy paste it.)

Input:

```
4
hello
how 
are
you
```

Output:

```
hello
how
are
you
```

Comment: I don't see any form of output at all. How are you running the program and providing input? If you're typing the input to stdin on the command-line itself, you'll see your own input barring some very intentional code making it work otherwise (disabling echo to stdout).

Comment: what you type into your console is not considered an output

Comment: You input `4` and then the 4 words `Hello`, `how`, etc. And that's all your code does. What do you expect?

Comment: why does it duplicates my input and show it as an output

Comment: guys I put the picture there if you check I think that you can understand what I meant

Comment: It is an online compiler issue. Change to something having fewer bugs

Comment: If you have to copy-and-paste the text to get the effect [i.e. but you do _not_ get it if you enter the data char-by-char, by hand], then if you're seeing this, it is an artifact of the terminal emulator/IDE/online compiler that the program is running in. It is your machine clipboard mechanism that is doing this. The clipboard does an echo and the IDE does a second echo. It has _nothing_ to do with your program code. The effect will occur even if your program does _no_ input of any sort. Try doing the same under an `xterm` window on a linux machine.

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you so much all this time I thought that it gives that duplication as an output. again thank you for this explanation.

Comment: @ElvinQarayev If you can edit the question with the URL to the online compiler you are using, this might be a pretty good question. Other beginners could have similar problems with it.

Comment: If you're just reading from a file by redirecting `stdin` (e.g. `./myprogram < input`) _and_ the intention is to read from a file, you [probably] _don't_ need to use `printf` to "prompt" for input. This is a simple way to read a file, instead of passing the name in `argv`, then doing (e.g.) `FILE *xf = fopen(argv[1],"r"); fscanf(xf,"%d",&n);` However, if you're doing `scanf` to get input from a user interactively, it helps to prompt them. That is, `scanf("%d",&n);` --> `printf("Enter count: "); fflush(stdout); scanf("%d",&n);`

Comment: Note that `scanf` can become desynchronized from the prompts, if the user inadvertently enters _two_ items instead of one. I prefer to use `fgets` when getting interactive input. See my answer: [Check if all values entered into char array are numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013419/5382650) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better example from an online compiler:
https://godbolt.org/z/joYdsdc11 As you can see (right window below stdin/input), there is no output.

Here is a fixed program (I also removed global variables since using them is bad practice):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int n;
    char s[50];
    
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d\n", n);

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s",s);
        puts(s);
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
hello
how
are
you
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sjcMrq4vb