# What can I use for a user input (numbers) instead of scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

The user has to write a number in the programm. Is there something else I can use for a number input instead of scanf?

Comment: Use `fgets` and then `strtol` for `int` and `strtod` for `double`.

Comment: Do you get problems when you use `scanf`?

Comment: Avoid `scanf()` for _all_  input.  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: Hint: google _avoid scanf_

Comment: Please explain the reasons for avoiding scanf. That is needed to recommend an alternative and for verifying that we are not looking at a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Reasons to avoid scanf: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Stop thinking of it as "user input".  It is input.  Whether it comes from a human or a socket or a file or anything else is (mostly) irrelevant.

Comment: You have multiple options, depending on the standard functions you like to use. Did you look through the usual documentation? Why does it not help you?

Comment: For user _interactive_ input with a prompt (e.g. `printf("Enter a number: "); fflush(stdout); int num; scanf("&d",&num);`), I recommend `fgets` followed by `strtol`. See my answer: [Check if all values entered into char array are numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013419/5382650)

Comment: user378246, what should happen if input is not in the number's range or is non-numeric?  It is that question that drives the best way to handle input.

Comment: You may want to take a look at my function `get_int_from_user` from [this answer of mine to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73915292/12149471). That function will automatically reprompt the user for input if the input is invalid, for example if the user does not enter a number.