# I have a problem with the realloc instruction in my program

Tags: c++, linux, oop, realloc

I'm making a program in C++ on Linux using object orientation.

I have to do an exercise that consists of defining a `parking` class and a `car` class. Every time I want to let a `car` enter the parking lot, depose an automatic object and enter the license plate data, time of entry, date of entry and category of the vehicle.

But, for every time I want to create a new auto object in line 67 inserting the new `car`, it gives me an error:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2 
fish: Job 1, './a.out' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "CountCharacters.h"


class Automobile{

    public:
        Automobile(void);
        char *Targa, *Categoria, *OraArrivo, *DataArrivo;
        bool memorizzata;
};

Automobile::Automobile(void)
{
    Targa = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 12);
    Categoria = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 15);
    OraArrivo = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 9);
    DataArrivo = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 12);
    memorizzata = false;
    
}

class Posteggio{

    public:
        Posteggio();
        int ingresso_automobile(Automobile *AutoM);
        void stampa_auto_presenti(Automobile *AutoM);
        
    private:
        const int max_posti = 350;
        int posti_occupati;
        int *minuti_trascorsi_auto;


};

Posteggio::Posteggio()
{
    
    posti_occupati = 0;

}

void Posteggio::stampa_auto_presenti(Automobile *AutoM)
{
    system("clear");

    for (int i = 0; i < posti_occupati; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("Veicolo numero: [%i], targa: [%s] , data arrivo: [%s], ora di arrivo: [%s], categoria veicolo: [%s] \n", i + 1, &AutoM[i].Targa, &AutoM[i].DataArrivo,&AutoM[i].OraArrivo, &AutoM[i].Categoria);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n\n ========= PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE =========\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();

}
int Posteggio::ingresso_automobile(Automobile *AutoM)
{
    
    if(posti_occupati > 0 && posti_occupati < 351)
    {
        
        system("clear");
        AutoM = (Automobile *)realloc(AutoM, sizeof(Automobile)  * (posti_occupati + 1)); // line 67
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Inserire targa: ");
        scanf("%s", &AutoM[posti_occupati ].Targa);

        fflush(stdin);        
        printf("Inserire data di arrivo: ");
        scanf("%s", &AutoM[posti_occupati ].DataArrivo);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Inserire ora di arrivo: ");
        scanf("%s", &AutoM[posti_occupati ].OraArrivo);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Inserire categoria del veicolo: ");
        scanf("%s", &AutoM[posti_occupati ].Categoria);
        fflush(stdin);
        posti_occupati++;

    } else if (posti_occupati == 0) {
        
        system("clear");
        printf("Inserire targa: ");
        scanf("%s", &AutoM[posti_occupati].Targa);

        printf("Inserire data di arrivo: ");
        scanf("%s", &AutoM[posti_occupati].DataArrivo);
        
        printf("Inserire ora di arrivo: ");
        scanf("%s", &AutoM[posti_occupati].OraArrivo);

        printf("Inserire categoria del veicolo: ");
        scanf("%s", &AutoM[posti_occupati].Categoria); 
        posti_occupati = posti_occupati + 2;

    } else {
        system("clear");
        printf("Spiacenti, posti esauriti!");
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    Posteggio posteggio1;
    Automobile *AutoM;
    
    int scelta_menu;
    AutoM =  (Automobile *)malloc(sizeof(Automobile));

    while(scelta_menu != 1)
    {
        
        system("clear");
        std::cout << "1)Exit\n2)Ingresso nuova auto\n3)Info auto presenti\n4)Modifica dati automobili\n5)Stampa elenco auto presenti\n6)Stampa statistiche\n--: ";  
        std::cin >> scelta_menu;
        
        switch (scelta_menu)
        {
            case 2: posteggio1.ingresso_automobile(AutoM);break;
            case 3: posteggio1.stampa_auto_presenti(AutoM);break;
            default: continue;
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

I think the problem is on line 67, and I tried to change the multiplication between `sizeof(automobile)` and `posti_occupati`, but I always get an error doing the input.

Comment: C has no classes. Pulled the tag

Comment: With that out of the way, `realloc` is a C function and has no clue what a class is. It just slings around blocks of memory, so use it at your own risk.

Comment: In C++ you should use container classes like `std::vector` rather that C-style arrays with `malloc()` and `realloc()`.

Comment: Recommendation: [Resolve these compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/6hfjExW37). That said, you might not be getting most of these warnings because C++ (and C) offer no guarantee of any diagnostic if you misuse variable arguments. Consider using C++'s streaming IO to get compiler errors when you screw this stuff up or, if your compiler's up to date, [the format library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format)

Comment: `Automobile` looks trivial enough for survive `malloc` and `realloc`, but you're still better off not using C's `*alloc` functions in C++ unless you're working at the very bottom of the language writing low-level infrastructure functions.

Comment: . . . except for the reliance on the members being initialized by the constructor that never gets called.

Comment: Don't use `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` etc in C++.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is UB (undefined behavior). Don't use it. You're using it compensate for `scanf` not removing newlines (e.g. not being line oriented). Replace with `fgets` and `strcspn` to remove the newline. For some examples of how to use these and prompt a user, see my answer: [Check if all values entered into char array are numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013419/5382650)

Comment: So much of this code is clearly written with C in mind, not C++.  It needs a good re-write to handle C++ *properly*. `(m|re)alloc()`/`free()`, `printf()`/`scanf()`, `fflush()`, `getchar()`, it all needs to go BYE-BYE and be replaced with C++ equivalents (`std::vector`/`std::array`, `std::cin`/`std::cout`, etc) instead.